# Error installing IRkernel for Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm following the instruction here https://irkernel.github.io/installation/ and gets the error `package ‘pdbZMQ’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)` after the very first line of the instruction. Has anyone successfully installed the IRkenel for Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type following command in Anaconda console

```
conda install -c r r-essentials
```

After that open jupyter notebook you can see R kernel installed in it.